# How to change the Angular Material 2 CSS imports order?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

On an Angular 2 app, built with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), I've set up the [Angular 2 Material components](https://github.com/angular/material2) following the [official installation guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md).

Angular 2 Material is placing its main CSS styles in the page `<head>` always **below** my custom CSS styles. Which creates implications on my side if I need to override them.

How can I force Angular 2 Material to place its core CSS styles **above** the styles which I defined inside my Angular CLI main (entry) CSS file?

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you have placed the links in the .angular.cli.json, the styles array?

Comment: I haven't placed any other stylesheets in my `angular-cli.json`, except the entry (main) app `styles.scss`. The Angular 2 Material injects it's core CSS automatically as soon as I import it in my `app.module.ts` I think.

Comment: Curious to see the answer for this. It's a norm that the linked styles are added at the top in the cli application and then it append the required styles of the components and modules. Also, curious to know the reason why you want to do like that?

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk well, the reason is because it affects the specificity. Let's say I need to modify the `.mat-card` style. I write my modifications under let's say another class `.mat-card--huge`. I assign both classes to an element. My `.mat-card--huge` won't override the `.mat-card` styles. I need to bump-up the specificity in order to force `.mat-card--huge` to override the default `.mat-card` style. Which generally speaking is not a best practice.

Comment: @KaloyanKosev I've had trouble with this in the past too. I'm wondering if it is because of the shadow-dom? Have you tried playing with the ViewEncapsulation at all?

Comment: @yoonjesung no, I haven't tried. I feel a bit lost, I don't know yet what's the bottleneck for this one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, In Angular material it adds the intern CSS dynamically when the element/component gets load. So, you cannot change its order.

But to solve your problem, you can use CSS specificity to override it.
You can add your custom class in the body or the app-component and by using SCSS/CSS you can override material CSS with your own CSS.

Here is the example using SCSS, for change in checkbox styling. And `project__app` class name, which I have mentioned in the app-component. You can also use body instead of it or create a specific class on the parent to the element.

```css
.project__app
{
    /* checkbox customization */
    .mat-checkbox-layout
    {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mat-checkbox-inner-container
    {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    .mat-checkbox-frame {
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-width: 1px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround. But given how Angular Material works, there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is due to having some references to your css files in the index.html and having others in the angular-cli.json file.

Below is an example of my angular.cli json file and index.html

[image]

[image]

Whatever you have defined in index.html is going to come before what you have defined in the angular-cli.json file. If you want to reorder them, include references to all css files in the angular-cli.json file.

Notice how my styles.css file is the last thing listed in the angular-cli.json file.

---

**Edit (after rereading the original question again)**

I think you need to create your own custom theme and import it.

Per Angular Material's documentation

> In order to style your own components with Angular Material's tooling, the component's styles must be defined with Sass.
>
> All you need is to create a @mixin function in the custom-component-theme.scss

See Angular Material's documentation on [Theming your Own Components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components) and their [Theming Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Answer (score 0):

import material theme in style.css file on root:

e.g.

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

you can replace indigo-pink.css own your choice.

Comment: He's not talking about the styles that you import, but the styles compiled from modules such as `MatButtonModule`. These get added to the html automatically without the need for import.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by loading the custom css after the view has loaded.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.linkExternalStyleSheet('assets/styles/custom-theme.css');
  }

  linkExternalStyleSheet(externalStyleSheetUrl: string) {
    const overrideStyleSheet: any = document.getElementById('extStyleLink');
    if (overrideStyleSheet) {
      overrideStyleSheet.href = externalStyleSheetUrl;
    } else {
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.id = 'extStyleLink';
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.media = 'screen';
      link.href = externalStyleSheetUrl;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
  }
}
```